# php fopen() to access controlled remote drive

Tags: php, jquery, csv

I would like to use php to write the results of a MS SQL (2008R2) query to a remote share drive.  The drive has access control but all users (including myself) are approved for access.  When I run the fopen() and fputcsv() on my server and place the csv on the remote share drive folder it works fine.  When I try to execute the php via an AJAX call tied to a button (#testing) it gives me (where actual file path replaced with remoteDrive:

fopen(\\remoteDrive\file.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dart\fetchdata.php** on line 19

fetchdata.php:

```
<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=(local);Database=dart");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode("Error connecting to the server.");
    die ();
}

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT *
          FROM dbo.table";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

try {
    $sth->execute();

    $fp = fopen('\\\\remoteDrive\\file.csv','w');

    $array = ["name","layer","type"];
    fputcsv($fp,$array);

    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($fp,$row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode("Error submitting the query.");
    die ();
}

fclose($fp);
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','#tester', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type:  'POST',
        url: 'fetchdata.php',
        success:  function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    })
})
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: your test with php code, was made behind the apache server, or directly via command line "php yourScript.php" ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis he uses IIS.  And for the topic starter - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078542/using-phps-fopen-in-windows-on-a-network-drive

Comment: Yes, I am using IIS.  I am not referencing drive letter but, instead, using the full network path.  I use JetBrains for stack development so I am debugging directly from JetBrains on my server (VM).  That process works, I just get the failure when AJAX calls to the php file.